# refresh token in passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, refresh-token

I am new in laravel. I am using laravel passport for authentication in APIs for mobile app. Now i want to know that how can i achieve following functionality.

- I want to expire my current accesstoken within 24 hours.
- After expire current accesstoken i want to refresh my accesstoken.
- using that refreshed accesstoken i want to access app.

Can anyone help me to solve this. I have create following code to generate token as well as to refresh token

## My login function code

```
$client = \Laravel\Passport\Client::where('password_client', 1)->first();
        $request->request->add([
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $client->id,
            'client_secret' => $client->secret,
            'scope' => null,
            'username' => request('email'),
            'password' => request('password'),
        ]);
        $proxy = Request::create(
                        'oauth/token', 'POST'
        );
        $tokens = \Route::dispatch($proxy);
        $tokrnresponse = (array) $tokens->getContent();
        $tokendata = json_decode($tokrnresponse[0]);

echo $tokendata->access_token
```

will give me accesstoken and

```
echo $tokendata->refresh_token
```

will give me refresh token
now from postman i am try to refresh token using another api called refresh_token(). i am passing access token in header.

## refresh_token() Code

```
$client = \Laravel\Passport\Client::where('password_client', 1)->first();
    $request->request->add([
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'refresh_token' => '<refresh_token>',
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'scope' => null
    ]);
    $proxy = Request::create(
                    'oauth/token', 'POST'
    );
    $tokens = \Route::dispatch($proxy);
    $tokrnresponse = (array) $tokens->getContent();
    $tokendata = json_decode($tokrnresponse[0]);
    print_r($tokendata);
    exit;
```

I got new access token using above code, but when i try to access other api using refreshed access token then it gives me "Unauthenticated" error. can anyone help me.